# Onekeypress AttributeError?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.4, turtle-graphics, attributeerror

(Python 3.4, in Windows XP Professional)
In a turtle program that I started recently, Onekeypress doesn´t work. I tried other things like "onekey" or "onekeyrelease", but they don´t work either. It gives me an AttributeError.

Here is the code:

```
    import turtle
import time

posp=0.1

#Ventana
w = turtle.Screen()
w.title("SNAKE")
w.bgcolor("black")
w.setup(width=600, height=600)
w.tracer(0)

#Cabeza serpiente
cabeza=turtle.Turtle()
cabeza.speed(0)
cabeza.shape("square")
cabeza.color("white")
cabeza.penup()
cabeza.goto(0,0)
cabeza.direction="stop"

#Funciones
def mov():
    if cabeza.direction=="up":
        y=cabeza.ycor()
        cabeza.sety(y+20)
    if cabeza.direction=="down":
        y=cabeza.ycor()
        cabeza.sety(y-20)
    if cabeza.direction=="right":
        x=cabeza.xcor()
        cabeza.setx(x+20)
    if cabeza.direction=="left":
        x=cabeza.xcor()
        cabeza.setx(x-20)

def up():
    cabeza.direction="up"
def down():
    cabeza.direction="down"
def right():
    cabeza.direction="right"
def left():
    cabeza.direction="left"

#Teclado
w.listen()
w.onekeypress(up,"Up")

while True:
    w.update()

    mov()
    time.sleep(posp)
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad english, I´m from Spain.

Comment: For future reference, please provide the full stack-trace. The problem you're having is that you have misspelled the attribute `onkeypress` as `onekeypress`.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: @HampusLarsson How do you write then? Something like  ´´´ onekeypress(up,"Up")´´´? It doesn´t work.

Comment: Is there any alternative for onekeypress? Or maybe any other way to do the same?

Comment: The comments above are literal, it's not ***one*** it's ***on*** as in it's not 'one' key being pressed but rather 'on' the pressing of a key.

Comment: Oh! What a mistake... I´m sorry. Thanks and sorry, I´m so stupid... x-{

Comment: It´s possible to upvote answers or something in Windows XP? I can´t.

Answer (score 0):

*This was answered in the comments by Hampus Larsson. Copying this comment to an actual answer.*

The problem you're having is that you have misspelled the attribute `onkeypress` as `onekeypress`.